# How would i delete an object from an instance table from a Many-to-Many relationship without removing the actual object data when I am doing PUT/PATCH

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Below is my model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)

class Image(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

My serializer:

```
class imagesSerializer(QueryFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = CreatableSlugRelatedField(
        many=True, 
        queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
        slug_field='tag',
        required= False
    )
   class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('id','name','tags')
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
        for item in validated_data:
           if Image._meta.get_field(item):
               setattr(instance, item, validated_data[item])
        Tag.objects.filter(image=instance).delete()
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            instance.tags.delete()
            tag_id, created=Tag.objects.get_or_create(tag=tag_data)
            instance.tags.add(tag_id)
        instance.save()
      return instance
```

Now Three tables are getting created after migrations:
 1. Image
 2. Tag
 3. Image_Tags 
While updating the tags data my old tag data is getting deleted in both Tag and Image_Tags tables. Now I want to delete the existing tag data for that image from image_tags table only not in the Tag table.

How to achieve this using Django?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `delete()` on a queryset deletes all the objects in the queryset so `instance.tags.delete()` and `Tag.objects.filter(image=instance).delete()` delete all the tags (you're doing the same thing multiple times btw).

Use `clear()` to remove all relations or even better use `set()` to just set the entire set of relations in one go (look at the bottom of [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/))

Comment: i have tried using set() but i dont know i was unable to get the result, so i tried with clear() ,its workiing now... Thanks